# Progress database, OpenLink, OpenEdge compatibility

Tags: odbc, openedge, progress-db

I am configuring several Windows 10 systems that will need to reliably connect via ODBC using system DSNs to both Progress version 9.x and Progress version 10.x databases.
I have been told by one of our IT staff that interfacing with Progress versions 9.x servers require the OpenLink ODBC client software, while interfacing with Progress 10.x requires the OpenEdge ODBC client software.

I am not completely confident that this is true, but I have not been able to find any authoritative documentation citing version compatibilities between these technologies/products.  Can someone please direct me to information about the compatibility between these products, pertaining specifically to versions of these products?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was version 8 that required OpenLink.

Version 9 is unspeakably ancient and version 10 not much better.  The current release is OpenEdge 12.  ODBC options for v9 should include Progress/Datadirect ODBC since the SQL-92 engine was introduced in that timeframe.  Documentation for such things is going to be very, very sparse.

Progress' current ODBC documentation: https://www.progress.com/odbc/openedge might get you started though.

OpenLink does also support v9 and they have some documentation here: http://wikis.openlinksw.com/UdaWikiWeb/MigratingFromSQL89ToProgress10SQL92Connectivity

Answer (score 2):

In the Progress 9 windows client, there is a 32bit ODBC driver for Progress 9. However, if the program you are trying to connect to Progress from is 64 bit, this will not work directly.

We have succeeded in using an old 32bit version of SQL Server as a tunnel, creating SQL Server views on the Progress database and querying these views using a SQL Server ODBC driver from the 64 bit program.

It's messy and awkward, and I wouldn't want to vouch for the robustness of such a solution, but if this is only a stopgap then perhaps it may help.

Answer (score 0):

OpenLink provide Progress SQL-92 ODBC Driver for version 9.x, 10.x & 11.x and can provide such connectivity to both 32 & 64 bit Windows applications, see http://wikis.openlinksw.com/UdaWikiWeb/InstallProgress92LiteWin32 ...

Comment: While the link might contain information that answers the question, please consider making use of the space that StackOverflow allows for answers. Please consider including some of the relevant info from the link in the space provided for your answer.